How to display text in different languages?
I am having hard time finding a solution to display text written in other languages.
Here is the issue:
Player login in my game through Facebook and Facebook provides data alongside users name. Now if the name is in English then everything works perfectly fine, but if it is written in other language, e.g. Hindi or Bangla, then it is not displayed in the Android build. However I can clearly see it in Unity Editor.
So far, I have tried to use Hindi Fonts in unity to display the text but shows empty inside the Text UI and in the print call as well.
This is the Hindi name I have received from Facebook:
"name":"\u0930\u093e\u092e"

Result when displayed this text in Legacy Text and TMP Text in the Unity Editor:

Result when displayed in the Android device:



My code:
public void Click() {
        var check = "\u0930\u093e\u092e";
        Debug.Log(check);
        text.text = "LagacyText " + check;
        Debug.Log($"text: {text.text}");
        text2.text = "TMP Text " + check;
        Debug.Log($"text2: {text2.text}");
    }

As we can see the text I have received from Facebook is in Unicode format and in Hindi Language and when I display it inside Unity Editor it works great but situation is completely different in Android build.
My goal is simple to display the player's name as I have received it from Facebook, regardless of its language.

It looks like you have chosen a font that does not include those glyphs.  Experiment with your font choice.

I have tried a Font called Chanakya which include Hindi Symbols but unfortunately result were the same

but the screenshots clearly show that the unicode (hindi) signs are searched in the wrong font: LiberationSans. Check that the TextMeshPro object has the correct font asset assigned and that the font asset is setup correctly, either bake the signs you need or prolly more useful in your case change the atlas population mode to dynamic

@nkazz what about LegacyText ? I have assigned the correct font their yet not worked, any guidance?

In my experience the Arial and Noto font cover many languages. This might help finding a suitable Google font.

is there any step by step guidance? or tutorials?

You should capture the name in the user's "local Font and language"; convert it to a PNG  (or vector graphic for better scaling) via a capture of the screen visual; and manage the "visible" name that way; like an avatar.

Importing Fonts
Creating static fonts:

Download the font to use as a .ttf
Window > TextMeshPro > Font Asset Creator from the menu bar
Select the downloaded .ttf as the source file
(optional) Configure font settings like padding, character set, etc.

Creating dynamic fonts

Download the font to use as a .ttf

Either
a. Right Click on .ttf Font > Create > Text Mesh Pro > Font Asset
b. Click on .ttf Font and use CTRL + Shift + F12


Solutions for TMP Text
For something like this, you can either one use font that supports basically every language in one font (something like Arial), or you can use multiple different fonts, each supporting some subset of characters. With the second approach you can use a certain (probably stylized) font when supported, and a different font if those aren't available.

For one monolithic font (like Arial), it's best to keep the font's "atlas" (a large texture used to render the font) set to "dynamic". This is because it's basically impossible to fit every unicode character within the 4096x4096 max texture resolution at a reasonable sampling size. You can change an existing font to be dynamic through the Generation Settings > Atlas Population Mode property, or the "Update Atlas Texture" button on the top right of the font's inspector window.
For using fallback fonts, simply pick one main font and add the other languages' fonts as fallback options in the order of the fallback list (marked "D" within this image). Then, whenever your main font encounters a character that it does not contain, it will check through the fallback fonts to find the correct character. If it doesn't end up finding anything, it creates the squares that you saw before.

The best approach, if you don't need a stylized font, is to just stick with one dynamic monolithic font. The second best option would be to use a monolithic font as a fallback (like Arial), where it only uses it when your main stylized font lacks certain characters.
Solution for Legacy Text
There's a somewhat functional fallback system available like with TMP fonts, but the only guaranteed way is to just use a font with basically every unicode character (like Arial.)
Even better would just be upgrading these objects to use TMP text and fonts. The commonly accepted solution for supporting a "fallback chain" type thing with legacy text is to just manually detect and change the font used per language, which hardly seems like a solution to me. Which also doesn't support multiple languages in one line of text. Probably more work than changing out legacy text for TMP text.

Thanks for your answer. I was able to display other languages text e.g. Bengali / Hindi but they are not appearing correctly. E.g. "श्री" or "ध्वनि" (Hindi Words) & "রাসেল" (Bengali word) shows up like this: https://imgur.com/a/oqTjjkr

Unity has difficulties displaying scripts like of these kinds, including languages like arabic. There's not much you can do without waiting for them to update it. It's being worked on for Unity 6, but not for TMP.

I wonder how other games made in unity is able to do that?

Some languages have scripts made to add dedicated support, like Arabic. I don't think this is usable in your case since you have to support ANY language's text without even knowing which language it is.

try using below code
public void Click()
{
    var check = "\u0930\u093e\u092e";
    check = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(check);
    Debug.Log(check);
    text.text = "LagacyText " + check;
    Debug.Log($"text: {text.text}");
    text2.text = "TMP Text " + check;
    Debug.Log($"text2: {text2.text}");
}

